# Naturality of an exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, functors, natural-transformations

I was reading [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/107745/137215) post about the Künneth theorem, to try to understand what it is.

I don't really understand what it means for a sequence to be natural. Does this mean we have a natural transformation between some functors? Which ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F, G, H:C\rightarrow Ab$ are a functors to an Abelian category. Suppose that for every object $A$ there exists an exact sequence  $F(A)\rightarrow G(A)\rightarrow H(A)$. This sequence is natural if and only if  for every morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$,

$\matrix{ F(A)&\rightarrow &G(A)&\rightarrow& H(A)\cr
F(f)\downarrow &&G(f)\downarrow &&\downarrow H(f) \cr F(B)&\rightarrow &G(B)&\rightarrow& H(B)}$

is commutative.

Comment: thanks! It is clear now